# Dynamically generate single JSON by merging small module JSON files ReactJS React-Intl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I am working on the React-intl for the language translation. I have configured React-inlt in my application, it's working for the single login module. I have a separate language constant file for each module (Login, Register, Dashboard etc). I need to merge all small js/JSON file and need to generate a single js/JSON file. Because I need to import only one file, it should contain all module language data. How to achieve this one? Create appreciate.

```
<IntlProvider
                locale={locale.lang}
                messages={languageMsg[locale.lang]}
            >
```

Comment: You can require all json files, and then merge them with Object.assign. Something like this : `const msg1 = require('./msg1.json'); const msg2 = require('./msg2.json'); const all = Object.assign({}, msg1, msg2); <IntlProvider messages={all[locale.lang]} > ... `

Comment: Thanks for the reply, above codes works only merge 2 JSON  file objects. How to merge 4 to 6 JSON file objects?

Comment: Just add additional objects after the last one : `Object.assign({}, msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4 ....)` etc